# I want to generate random date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Can anyone please tell me I want to generate 100 random dates for my table:

```
create table dates (dt date)
```

This code is ok I want to put below code in loop so that it will generate 100 random dates

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(second, (rand() * 60 + 1), 
    DATEADD(minute, (rand() * 60 + 1),
    DATEADD(day, (rand() * 365 + 1), 
    DATEADD(year, -1, getdate())
```

or any other simple code to `generate random` date give me if you can.

Thanks

praviin

Comment: stored proc perhaps in sqlserver ?

Comment: a [link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/11/sql-server-while-loop-example-with.html) .. do what you are doing inside a BEGIN END block of a sqlserver 2008 stored proc with an insert stmt in a while loop

Comment: loop=loop+1 gives error  



Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'dt'.
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: i was giving a link to a concept. I have no clue what your code state is to understand that error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
select top 100 dateadd(ss, cast(abs(checksum(newid())) as int), '19000101') as rndDate
from master..spt_values
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6049

For predefined range:

```
with cte as(select row_number() over(order by number) % 366 r 
            from master..spt_values)
select top 100 dateadd(dd, r, '20141231') from cte order by newid()
```

`r` will contain values from 1 to 366. Adding to `'20141231'` will give values from desired range.

Comment: thank you Giorgi Nakeuri... :) you gave very simple code and its working... with insert query. 

can you also help me with given range of dates like 
----from date 2015-01-01 to given date 2015-12-31

Answer (score 0):

What you want is really only possible via stored procedures.  I'd recommend studying the [MySQL compound-statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html) syntax, especially [loop syntax.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html)

You'd have to put in your own date generation code, but code within this loop should run 10 times when called:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE iterateTen()
BEGIN
  DECLARE p1 INT DEFAULT 0;
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 < 10 THEN
     ITERATE label1;
    END IF;
   LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
END;
```

Comment: @Drew I guess maybe I shouldn't have assumed that.  If it turns out he isn't able to add stored procedures, I'm not sure there's anything he can do other than run it 100 times...  Then again, I'm far more familiar with PostgreSQL and there might be something unique to MySQL that allows for it.  I just wouldn't know of it.

Comment: same concept. I deleted the `mysql` tag due to the dateadd function (note no underscore), the getdate() function, and his explicit 2008 tag :)